# Skipping non-plain index 'ricerca_rt'

Tags: sphinx

When I am trying to run sphinx indexer I have this error

- skipping non-plain index 'ricerca'...

I have upgraded sphinx from version 2 to version 3, the problem above is for sphinx3, I have created research on google, but we have not so many solutions. I have added source attribute for index ricerca nothing changed, I have deleted sphinx data nothing changed. Index ricerca is used in application, and I have another error undefined local index ricerca (unknown local index 'ricerca'). The error - skipping non-plain index 'ricerca'.. is present on indexer simple and on indexer rotate.
The structure of index ricerca is :

```
index ricerca
    {
        type            = distributed
        local           = ricerca_main
        local           = ricerca_delta
        local           = ricerca_phantoms
        local           = ricerca_rt
    }
```

Anyone can help me?

Comment: Thats not an 'error', just a 'notice'. The 'ricerca' is of a type that can't be updated by indexer (its proabbly either a real-time index, or a distributed index) - its just telling you that indexer skipped it. Nothing more

Comment: No, index ricerca is used in application, and I have another error undefined local index ricerca (unknown local index 'ricerca').

Comment: Ok, well does it actully have `type=plain` in the defintion (or at least inheritied from one that does!) ?

Comment: The index ricerca has type distributed
{
 type   = distributed
 local   = ricerca_main
 local   = ricerca_delta
 local   = ricerca_phantoms
 local   = ricerca_rt
}

Comment: I have solved the problem, thankyou @barryhunter I have changed the type of index ricerca to be the same how are local ricerca_main type plain, and added the source the same how is on index ricerca_main